# Existence of the asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel

Tags: heat-equation

Theorem 2.26 in Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators says that the heat kernel of a Laplace type operator has a unique asymptotic expansion (the theorem and its proof are attached below). Unfortunately I think that the proof only shows the uniqueness, not the existence:

As far as I understand the proof shows that if $(\widetilde\Phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a solution, then it equals the sequence $(\Phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ defined in the theorem (hence uniqueness). But to proof existence we still need to show that $(\Phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a solution, don't we? That is, we have to prove that
\begin{equation}
\forall i>0:(\nabla_\mathcal R + i)\Phi_i=-B_x\Phi_{i-1},
\end{equation}
don't we? If you agree, does someone know how to complete the proof?

---

Let $H$ be a generalized Laplacian on the bundle $E$ over a compact manifold $M$ and let $B$ be the operator acting on sections of $E$ in a neighbourhood of y defined by the formula
\begin{equation}
B= |g|^{1/4} \circ H \circ |g|^{-1/4}.
\end{equation}
[image]